# How to add a ring around the custom image marker pointing down on the map without using drawable file

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, android-custom-view

[want marker like in the image. i have made a custom marker with a circular image but unable to add the ring around the circular image pointing down programmatically.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUJF9.jpg)

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    mMap = googleMap;

    Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ab), 120, 120, true);

    Bitmap image=getCircularBitmap(scaled);
```

// modify canvas
    //    canvas1.drawBitmap(scaled, 0,0, color);

```
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(sydney);
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(image));

    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}

public Bitmap getCircularBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    Bitmap output;

    if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
        output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    } else {
        output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getWidth(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();

    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    float r = 0;

    if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
        r = bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
    } else {
        r = bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
    }

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output
```

Answer (score 0):

Developers are required to use drawables that will be passed thru the `BitmapDescriptorFactory` as indicated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#customize_the_marker_image). The ring around the image should be part of the image itself, if its multi-colored (like on the image provided), you can just use multiple templates for the markers.

Hope this helps!